# Lumen inside lumen, possible?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I've normal server var/www/html where I've lumen project say lumen1. What I want to know is whether I can have lumen2 inside lumen1 folder

something like this

var/www/html/lumen1 - first lumen
var/www/html/lumen1/lumen2 - second lumen

I can't find any article even close to it, is it good practice? How to do it?

Comment: Whats the use case? It may be possible but is it really necessary?

Comment: Yeah possible if it is sub child of lumen1->lumen1-1 or if its incremental you should create inline with lumen1

Comment: @apokryfos I want separate vendor for each of the lumen

Comment: right now I'm working with routes, to point to inner lumen2, is it right approach? @poldo

Comment: I got the solution, I can simply run http://localhost/lumen1/lumen2/public/functionName from the lumen2 routes

Comment: What's the purpose? Is one site a subsite of the other one or are they supposed to be different sites?

Comment: we've exisiting project and we're adding more functionality for it, maybe composer update is not feasible for us at this moment(I don't know the exact reason), I'm being told to do so.